# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string when using scanner to read the file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not sure why I am receiving this error and what's the fix to it in the following snippet of code:

```
        String srcFile=args[0];
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(srcFile);
        //    if (fileIn.isFile() && fileIn.canRead())

        CarDB carDatabase = new CarDB();
        while(fileIn.hasNext())
        {       
          String[] line = fileIn.nextLine().split(",");
          double mpg = Double.parseDouble(line[0]);
          int cylinders = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
          int power = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
          int year = Integer.parseInt(line[3]);
          int region = Integer.parseInt(line[4]);
          String makerName = line[5].trim();
          String carName = line[6].trim();

          carDatabase.addCar(makerName, carName, mpg, cylinders, power, year, region);// add car
          carDatabase.addMaker(makerName);//add maker to list

        }
```

and line 36 is : `double mpg = Double.parseDouble(line[0]);`

Error is:

```
java CarDBMain cars.txt 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cars.txt"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at CarDBMain.main(CarDBMain.java:36)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having this `Scanner fileIn = new Scanner("cars.txt");` so your first line will be `"cars.txt"`

```
 Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(srcFile));//Or probably path of file
```

Here create file and pass the `commandline argument`,means file path,to File constructor and pass that file to [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

You are passing file name as `String` to Scanner.

Constructors

```
Scanner(File source)<---Takes File you want to read
Scanner(String source)<----Takes String you want to read
etc.
```

Comment: Well, this is a project in which I believe we are not supposed to change that specific line. Can we incorporate this any other way?

Comment: well, isn't the file name a string?

Comment: But it will take that String  as input while you want to pass file from which you are reading.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. Will be accepting the answer in 6 minutes :) Apparently it was a typo or possibly they wanted us to catch it somehow!